# A little change in unsrtnat

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am using `natbib` and `unsrtnat.bst`. I want to change `FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}` and `FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}` in order to get something like this:

> page 12-34, chapter 5 in Very nice book

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is quite an odd format. I suppose it can be done, but then what is to happen to the editors (if any)? Is it "pp. 12-34, ch. 5 in Ditor, E: Very nice book" or "pp. 12-34, ch. 5 in Very nice book ed. by E. Ditor"? If you use this for `@incolletion`s only it will be inconsistent with `@articles`, as these will still have "J. Art. 5(6): 12-34".

Comment: @moewe It will be the second variant: "pp. 12-34, ch. 5 in Very nice book ed. by E. Ditor" and it will be only for `@incollection`. I am not concerned `@articles`, in will stay as it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can actually be done with `natbib` and `bibtex`, though quite some attention has to be paid to getting the capitalisation right.

You will have to modify `unstrnat.bst`, so find it, copy it to a location LaTeX can find it and rename it to, say, `myunsrtnat.bst`.

Open `myunsrtnat.bst`.

Find `FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}` and replace it with

```
FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages.incoll
    { type empty$
        { "Chapter" }%<--- that is changed
        { type "l" change.case$ }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.connect
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { ", " * format.pages.incoll * }%<--- changed call to format.pages.incoll
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Then add the following to the file

```
FUNCTION {format.pages.incoll}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
        { chapter empty$
            { "Page" }
            { "page" }
          if$
          pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
        { chapter empty$
            { "Pages" }
            { "pages" }
          if$
          pages tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Find `FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}` and replace it with

```
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "" }
    { pages empty$ %<----------- this conditional is new
        { chapter empty$
            { "In " }
            { "in " }
          if$ }
        { "in " }
      if$%<--------------------- here it stops
      editor empty$
        { booktitle emphasize * }%<--- no "in" anymore
        { format.editors * ", " * booktitle emphasize * }%<--- no "in" anymore
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Find `FUNCTION {inbook}` it contains the following lines

```
format.bvolume output
format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
new.block
```

change them to

```
format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
format.bvolume output
new.block
```

Finally, the same for `FUNCTION {incollection}`; you will find

```
  format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  format.chapter.pages output
  new.sentence
```

replace that with

```
  format.chapter.pages output
  format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  new.sentence
```

In your document, use `\bibliographystyle{myunsrtnat}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`.

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{testbook,
  author        = {Walter Ordsmith},
  title         = {The Work},
  subtitle      = {Subtitle},
  year          = {1983},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher \& Co.},
  address       = {Townsville},
}
@article{testart1,
  author  = {Steven C. Ientist},
  title   = {Thrilling, Intelligent and True Limes of Erudition},
  journal = {Journal of Articles},
  volume  = {20},
  number  = {3},
  year    = {1935},
  pages   = {1--46},
}
@incollection{ordChap1,
  author     = {Walter Ordsmith},
  title      = {A Chapter},
  booktitle  = {The Second Work},
  publisher  = {Academic Press},
  year       = {1977},
  pages      = {12--34},
  chapter    = {2},
}
@incollection{ordChap2,
  author     = {Walter Ordsmith},
  title      = {A Chapter},
  booktitle  = {The Second Work},
  publisher  = {Academic Press},
  year       = {1977},
  pages      = {12--34},
}
@incollection{ordChap3,
  author     = {Walter Ordsmith},
  title      = {A Chapter},
  booktitle  = {The Second Work},
  publisher  = {Academic Press},
  year       = {1977},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{myunsrtnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]